# How to skip the luksFormat prompt?

Tags: linux, luks

If I setup a new luks volume with "cryptsetup --verbose --cipher=aes-cbc-essiv:sha256 --key-size=256 luksFormat /dev/foo /my/keyfile" it requires me to enter "YES" to actually do anything. Is there a way to skip this prompt, so I can just run it from a script?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`--batch-mode` should do exactly that.